# Creating a build environment to build Tensorflow apps with cmake

Tags: tensorflow, cmake

I am wondering if there is a definitive recipe for using cmake to build tensorflow and tensor for apps. I followed the instructions at https://github.com/cjweeks/tensorflow-cmake without much success and ended up having to build Eigen and Protobuf by hand and then copy relevant headers files into the the header file tree created by the Bazel build of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I just built TF with CMake, VS2017, and CUDA 9.2, but had to make two manual changes:

1. Patch *Half.h* in Eigen
2. Change CUDA version from "9.0" to "9.2" in the main CMakeLists.txt.

Build has to be single threaded, otherwise VS runs out of heap (on my 16GB laptop). It takes a while and one project fails, but builds enough libraries to run all the examples I wanted.

Another problem with CMake build, vs. Bazel, is that the former rebuilds a bunch of projects (involving protobuf generated files) even when nothing there changes. Bazel is smarter and only compiles the changed code, then statically links all object files into a single executable, which is still faster than CMake build.